# How can I call an on_pre_enter function in Kivy for my root screen?

Tags: python, kivy

Alright, at the moment I am writing a program. It has multiple screens controlled via ScreenManager. The root screen (the one that is shown when the program is loaded) has a label which text differs depending on the context of an external file. Originally, I was going to use something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open(*file*) as f:
        data = eval(f.read())
    App.run()
```

And, inside of said root screen:

```
def on_pre_enter(self):
    if data == *something*:
        self.ids.*widget_id*.text = *something else*
```

It works on any other screen but the root one. I have done some research and learnt that the given function (as well as on_enter) does not work on root screen because of the way event_dispatch works. So, is there any way around it, or anything I could do?

Edit: Minimal Reproducible Example.

```
main.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class WindowOne(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.ids.label_one.text = data

class WindowTwo(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.ids.label_two.text = data

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return design

data = ''
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('design.kv') as f:
        design = Builder.load_string(f.read())
    with open('data.txt') as f:
        data = eval(f.read())
    TestApp().run()

design.kv

Manager:
    WindowOne:
    WindowTwo:

<WindowOne>:
    name: "one"
    Label:
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.15, "y": 0.15}
        id: label_one
        font_size: 40
        text: "This Is Window One"
    Button:
        size_hint: (0.2, 0.2)
        on_release:
            app.root.current = 'two'

<WindowTwo>:
    name: "two"
    Label:
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.15, "y": 0.15}
        id: label_two
        font_size: 40
    Button:
        size_hint: (0.2, 0.2)
        on_release:
            app.root.current = 'one'
```

Code works just fine if you change on_pre_enter to on_pre_leave for WindowOne, but returns

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

otherwise.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. When I use a `ScreenManager`, the initial `Screen` gets its `on_pre_enter()` called.

Comment: @JohnAnderson done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `on_pre_enter()` method is being called as expected. The problem is that you are referencing the `ids` dictionary in that method, and the `ids` are net yet set (causing the error you see). So, you need to delay the `on_pre_enter` call until the `ids` are defined. One way to do that is to create a `DummyScreen` as your initial `Screen`, then use `Clock.schedule_once()` to switch to your original root `Screen`. To do that, define `DummyScreen` as:

```
class DummyScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.switch_screen)

    def switch_screen(self, dt):
        self.manager.transition = NoTransition()
        self.manager.current = "one"
        self.manager.transition = SlideTransition()
```

And in your `kv` file, add the `DummyScreen`:

```
Manager:
    DummyScreen:
    WindowOne:
    WindowTwo:
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!